# Cast entire matlab workspace to some class

Tags: matlab, casting

I'm looking for a way to cast the entire workspace in matlab to some class (say `double`).
For simplicity, lets just assume that only "simple" classes are present in the workspace (no cells or structs). Of course I can go line by line and change each variable, `x=double(x)` , but that's not practical if I have several 100's of variables. This is what I've wrote so far:

```
% # generate some variables of different classes
a1=int32(120);
a2=single(rand(10));
a3=double(rand(20));  
a4=(rand(5)>0.5);  %# logical

% # collect workspace variables using `whos` 
ws=whos;

for ii=1:size(ws,1)
     [ ? ] =   double(eval(ws(ii).name))
end
```

The last line `double(eval(ws{1,ii}))` performs the casting, but how should I assign it's output automatically to the original variables names?

You are also welcome to suggest an alternative way to cast all variables of the workspace, if you can think of one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question (+1). What about this?

```
ws = whos; %# Obtain workspace
for n = 1:size(ws,1)
    eval([ws(n).name, ' = double(', ws(n).name, ');']); %# Assign to double
end
```

This worked for me on R2012b. The trick is to alter the variable type and assign it with one call to `eval`.